# SYSDATE - 2YEARS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this in a query

```
from STG_WLT_FN_GF where date_yyyymmdd >= 20191101 )
```

And I want, have date -2 years sysdate, it's possible ?

Vanessa

Comment: What is the data type of `date_yyyymmdd`? You are comparing it to a `NUMBER` literal and then asking to compare it to the output of `SYSDATE`, which would be a `DATE` data type.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using the add_months function.

```
add_months(sysdate, 12 * -2)
```

Interval is known to have problems with certain dates (f.e. 31.03.) and it lacks the proper handling of leap years.
You would get an exception if executing the above answers code on 29.02.:

```
select to_date('29.02.2024') - interval '2' year from dual;
```

Where as following works:

```
select add_months(to_date('29.02.2024'), 12 * -2) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `interval` expression:

```
SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
```

Comment: This fails on 29th February.

Comment: @MT0: to be honest I consider that a bug in Oracle. That clearly violates how this is defined in the SQL standard (and obviously common sense as well)